# Getting an unwanted extra column in my HTML table

Tags: html, perl, cgi, html-table

Ok, I'm trying to make an HTML table to display some results from the finger command on my system, but I'm getting a leading column of blank space that I can't figure out how to remove. Here is the code I'm using.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use Modern::Perl;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;
use CGI qw/:standard *table *Tr/;

my @fingeroutput = `finger`;
my @info;
my @td;

foreach my $finger (@fingeroutput){
    $finger =~ /(\w+)\s+(\w*\s\w*)\s+(\w+\/\d+)\s+(\d*d*:*\d*)\s+(\w+\s\d+\s\d+:\d+)\s(.+)/;
        push (@info, ("$1", "$2", "$4", "$6") );
}

while (my @data = splice @info, 0, 4 ) {
    push @td, td( \@data );
}

print header(), start_html(-title=>'Basic Stuff');

print start_table({-border=>2, width=>"50%"});

print th([ 'Login', 'Name', 'Idle', 'Host']);
foreach my $row ( @td ) {
    print start_Tr;
    print td ( $row );
    print end_Tr;
}

print end_table;

print end_html();
```

The first problem I'm having is when the table prints out, the first row is always a row of blank space.

My second problem is that the Login column is coming up all blank space and all the data is shifted a cell to the right leaving my host section in a column with no header.

This is my first time working with CGI and HTML tables, so I've done a lot of research to get to this point. The only thing left is getting the table format right. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The second problem turned out to be in this code:

```
while (my @data = splice @info, 0, 4 ) {
    push @td, td( \@data );
}
```

By changing it to:

```
while (my @data = splice @info, 0, 4 ) {
    push @td, ( \@data );
}
```

I got rid of the extra leading column. I still haven't figured out why I'm getting a blank row to begin my table.

I did the quick fix of adding in a

```
shift @td;
```

If anyone can see why I was getting that blank row in the first place that would be helpful. Was it because I was using a push from the start to get my data in to the array?